# Gmail account ID is not sending error mail using ELMAH

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah, elmah.mvc

Its working fine if i am using domain email account like **test@xyz.com** but not working when i am using gmail email ID. My web config is below..

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="0"></security>
  <errorMail  from="test@gmail.com"
              to="test@gmail.com"
              subject="hii" 
              async="true"
              smtpPort="25" 
              useSsl="true"
              host="smtp.gmail.com"
              userName="test@gmail.com" 
              password="*******"/>
    </elmah>

  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod ="Network">
     <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" userName="test@gmail.com"   password="*******"/> </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.Model1.csdl|res://*/DAL.Model1.ssdl|res://*/DAL.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=CHETUIWK355\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Test;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this changes anything, but I found a bug in your ELMAH config using the [ELMAH Configuration Validator](https://elmah.io/tools/configvalidator). There's no `host` attribute in the `errorMail` element. Host, port etc. should be configured through `mailSettings`, which you do as well.

Comment: Yes, i replace `host` with `smtpServer` and then its successfully validate using the ELMAH Configuration Validator but mail is not sending. you can find the `host` attribute at the end of webconfig(please scroll the code section)